# Regex replace back

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with following situation:

```
private string _endPointPattern = @"X(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9-:]*)X";
```

Now if i want to get group, I just get it with:

```
match.Groups["name"]
```

Now let's assume reverted situation:

I want to insert string "Jerry" into named parameter to get XJerryX. 
How can I do that with Regex?

Comment: Can you please clarify and give an example of what you want to achieve maybe?

Comment: I want to insert text: Jerry into _endPointPattern, into the group <name> so the result will be XJerryX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `X` is a placeholder for some regular expression pattern (otherwise simply use `String.Replace`), this should work:

```
var yourInputString = "XX";
var replacement = "Jerry";
Regex.Replace(yourInputString,
              @"(X)(X)",
              String.Format(@"$1{0}$2", replacement));
```

**EDIT: after your comment (you might want to update the question):**

You need to update your regular expression, like so:

```
private string _endPointPattern =
   @"(?<prefix>X)(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9-:]*)(?<suffix>X)";
```

And then use:

```
var yourInputString = "XX";
var replacement = "Jerry";
var result = Regex.Replace(yourInputString,
                           _endPointPattern,
                           String.Format(@"${{prefix}}{0}${{suffix}}", replacement));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear question, but the code below works for multiple cases: `XX => XJerryX`, `XBobbyX => XJerryX`. But `XXavierX => XJerryXJerryX`.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=X).*?(?=X)", "Jerry");
```

Answer (score 0):

decPL your answer is the closest to the solution I needed. Nevertheless I have done it simpler way:

```
private const string EndPointFormat = @"X{0}X";

private const string Regex = @"(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9-:]*)";

private string _endPointPattern = string.Format(EndPointFormat, Regex);

string endPoint = string.Format(EndPointFormat, "Jerry");
```

Now I can use _endPointPattern to take the names from Regex and insert it back with string format.